# CollectionView Drag and Drop when embedded in PageViewController

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller, uicollectionviewdropdelegate

When using drag and drop with a UICollectionView embedded in a UIPageViewController, the delegate immediately triggers `didExit` when paging.

1. Begin Drag and Drop gesture
2. Page to new view
3. CollectionDropDelegate immediately fires:

- `newCV.didEnter`
- `oldCV.didExit`
- `newCV.didExit`

`newCV.didUpdate` is never called.  If we let go of the drop at this point it cancels.  My PageViewController is not fullscreen, so if I move the drag outside and back in I can still perform the drop after paging, but it's a bad user experience.

Notes:

- Not using UICollectionViewController
- CollectionView gets added to the UIViewController hierarchy in `viewDidLoad`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by toggling `collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled`.  Figuring out where in the lifecycle to do this was a bit challenging, and ultimately I ended up using the UIPageViewControllerDelegate `didFinishAnimating...`

So in my `ContentViewController.viewDidLoad`, I set `collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` and then in the delegate, I need to conditionally enable/disable the collection views.

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) { 
    if completed {
        guard let showing = pageViewController.viewControllers?.first as? DayViewController else {
            assertionFailure()
            return
        }
        
        // Disable All
        previousViewControllers.forEach {
            if let dayVC = $0 as? DayViewController {
                dayVC.collectionView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            }
        }
        // Enable Showing
        showing.collectionView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    } else {
        
        guard let showing = previousViewControllers.first as? DayViewController else {
            assertionFailure()
            return
        }
        
        // Disable All
        viewControllers?.forEach {
            if let dayVC = $0 as? DayViewController {
                dayVC.collectionView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            }
        }
        // Enable Showing
        showing.collectionView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
```